# "Required" validation not disabling submit in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a form that is still running the submit code even if required fields have not been filled out. In Chrome it will pop up with "please fill out this field", but only on text inputs (not dropdowns) and it still runs the submit method. Am I missing something really obvious?

```
             <form name="newForm">
                <div class="section">
                    <div layout="row" class="inputRow">
                        <label for="itemA">ITEM A</label>
                        <input flex class="lineInput" ng-model="vm.contract.itemA" name="itemA" id="itemA" type="text" required />
                        <label for="itemB">ITEM B</label>
                        <select flex ng-model="vm.contract.contractType" name="itemB" id="itemB" required>
                            <option ng-repeat="type in vm.typeList">{{type}}</option>
                        </select>
                        <md-checkbox class="md-primary" aria-label="Checkbox No Ink" ng-model="vm.contract.itemC" name="itemC" id="itemC">
                            ITEM C
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="row" class="inputRow">
                        <label for="itemD">ITEM D</label>
                        <md-datepicker flex ng-model="vm.contract.itemD" id="itemC" name="itemC" md-placeholder="Enter date" required></md-datepicker>
                        <label for="itemE">ITEM E</label>
                        <md-datepicker flex ng-model="vm.contract.itemE" id="itemE" name="itemE" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <md-button type="submit" data-ng-click="vm.save()">Save and continue</md-button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your vm.save function inside the controller you have to put something like this:

```
if ($scope.newForm.$valid){
   execute your code....
}
```

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable Chrome doing it's own validation, and instead designing your own (for dropdowns for example) you need to include the `novalidate` attribute to your form.

Second, as Gustavo pointed out, your form has `$valid`/`$invalid` properties attached by angular, which can be used in many different ways:

**Disable the save button:**

```
<md-button ng-disabled="newForm.$invalid" type="submit" data-ng-click="vm.save()">Save and continue</md-button>
```

**Moving the save function to the form using `ng-submit`**
This allows you to submit by pressing enter, better than using `ng-click` IMO.

```
<form name="newForm" ng-submit="newForm.$valid && vm.save()">
```

**Combining `ng-disabled` and `ng-submit`**

```
<form name="newForm" ng-submit="vm.save()">
    <md-button ng-disabled="newForm.$invalid" type="submit">Save and continue</md-button>
</form>
```

which is the best UX IMO

**Using it to controller**

```
if ($scope.newForm.$valid){
   execute your code....
}
```